Azure Function App (sometimes) missing default commands
I am in the process of developing an azure function app (powershell). The function app is made up of a number of functions that are triggered by various queues (and moves the state between the queues).
I am seeing occasions where when viewing the output of an invocation, I see the following error:
The term 'write-output:' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. Exception : Type : System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException
All of the child functions are using the same write-output command to write logging information to the host for troubleshooting reasons. This is causing some of my try catches to fail, as it is seeing the error when trying to output to the host.
I would have expected this to refresh the powershell session and restore anything that was missing
Example Code:

using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($QueueItem, $TriggerMetadata)

$QueueItem

if ($QueueItem.CollectautomationRunbookID) {
    write-output "Request is Pending. Put back into queue with 15 minute timeout"

}

#Edit:
So I took the script back to absolute basics as per example code, and the issue went away. When pasting my whole script back in, the issue reappears.
Going to use this to further troubleshoot, and will update if I solve it

please share your function code

Found the error in code.
write-output: $errors

For some reason, I had put a : after the write-output command. Removing this solved it.
Leaving this up in case someone faces similar in the future.
